# Is simultaneous graphical representation of real and complex solutions

Tags: complex-numbers

I am a 12th grade student revising complex numbers. While revising, I came across a typical example of a quadratic equation having no real solutions:

> $y = x^2 +1$ for $y = 0$

My question is: Can I use three mutually perpendicular axes: y axis, real x axis, and the imaginary axis, to simultaneously represent the solutions of this equation for various y values (simultaneously in the sense that in the same picture)?
 I tried it out (i.e. I drew the axes as described above and did the graphing; got the parabola for $ y\geq 1$
in the real x axis - y axis plane, and two straight lines in the imaginary axis - y axis for $y\lt1$), and I did not feel anything wrong in it.
I just wish to have the comfortable feeling that I am indeed not wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: Yes, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmHs1-hWPNs) video does something similar.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer Thank you very much!